# How to add products to Facebook Catalog using a pixel

Tags: facebook, pixel, facebook-pixel, product-catalog

✋ I have done and met all the requirements to build a "product catalog" based on the "Facebook pixel" but it doesn't work.

- I have the pixel connected to the catalog
- The pixel is well implemented in source code (verified)
- The pixel is receiving events (viewcontent, addtocart, purchases, etc.)
- The OpenGraph metadata are available when the ViewContent event is sent (verified).
- The OpenGraph metadata is well formed (verified).

Even more, I can verify all of these things with the Facebook Pixel Helper (image attached), and all it's right implemented. But when I try to choose the pixel as a "Product Data Source" the pixel is disabled... (so I cannot connect the pixel with my catalog)

[image: The pixel with events, but greyed out]
[image: The microdata, the opengraph and the requets]

Anyone can help me please? Is there any #bug using pixel as product data source?

Comment: What does _no esta listo_ mean, and have you checked what more information is hidden behind the question mark? (If you could switch your FB language to English before taking such screenshots, at least this kind of “what does that translate to” questions can be avoided ;-)

Comment: Sorry @CBroe, "no está listo" means, "it's not ready". https://i.snag.gy/nySYte.jpg It says, that you require to install the microdatas in the webpages, and a link to instructions... But as I told and I have demostrated in the screenshots, the microdata is perfectly implemented, I checked with opengraph debugger, the pixel helper, and even in network console.

Comment: Did you set up the OG meta data and/or the pixel recently? It says somewhere in the docs that it needs to be up & running for a certain time span before you can proceed with these net steps, I think.

Comment: As you can see here (https://i.snag.gy/8Quf34.jpg) my first try using a "typical" facebook ads account was in 11th of July, my second attempt using a "business manager" account was last week... but no way....

My question is... does anybody could get the pixel working as a "catalog data source"?  If so, could you please reproduce the exact steps, and tell me what type of pixel, microdata, etc. are you sending?

Comment: The pixel is not yet selected and is disabled, it will only be active if the site that is triggering the pixel does not give any error on the catalog, also make sure to trigger the View content event on the product detail page and send the required data with the trigger.

Comment: The pixel is not yet selected and is disabled, it will only be active if the site that is triggering the pixel does not give any error on the catalog, also make sure to trigger the View content event on the product detail page and send the required data with the trigger.

Comment: To add the products to the catalog using pixel you must send data of the product to Facebook by using any of the provided mechanism such as OpenGraph 

    <meta name="og:title" content="Proname" />
    <meta name="og:description" content="Product Description" />
    <meta name="og:url" content="https://myexample.com/procat/productname" />
    <meta name="og:image" content="https://myexample.com/images/virtuemart/product/hat2.png" />

Comment: Thanks @Pratyush but as I attached in the images, you can check that we are already sending the "view content" event in the product detail, and we are sending the right OpenGraph metadata, and we don't have any erros in Catalog. Still the checkbox to enable the "pixel to add products to catalog" is disabled and gray...

Comment: same here... I read here https://www.pixelyoursite.com/facebook-product-catalog-opengraph that we have to wait for 7 days after collecting datas from pixel in order to get that checkbox enabled. Let's wait and see...

Comment: Same problem @aleksdj, did you ever resolve this?

Comment: @abernier 10 days and still the pixel is "not ready" in my case.

Comment: In my case pixel is connected http://prntscr.com/mfkhmu but products are not adding into Catalog even pixel fires and Facebook pixel helper extension show everything is alright.http://prntscr.com/mfkira Does anyone know about it?

Comment: The issue keeps nowadays, I'm currently facing it too, although Facebook sends no errors when using the microdata debug tool. I leave it here just in case anybody wants to use it: https://business.facebook.com/ads/microdata/debug

Comment: Did you fix it? Are you sending all the required parameters to Pixel? Condition i.e.?

Answer (score 0):

Your Pixel is not active, Either you have to activate it by adding with tracking events in your web or activate it by manual events firing.

You can use Catalog Manager to associate pixels and apps to your catalog. Follow the below steps :-

1. Go to Catalog Manager.
2. Select the catalog you want to use.
3. Click Settings.
4. Next to Event Sources, click Edit.
5. Select a Facebook pixel and/or app, and then click Save.

For More Details Go through this link 
https://www.facebook.com/business/help/1044262445604547

Comment: The pixel is already connected, and has events, as I told in the first question:
You can check it here: https://i.snag.gy/l3y8K9.jpg

Answer (score 0):

The pixel is not yet selected and is disabled, it will only be active if the site that is triggering the pixel does not give any error on the catalog, also make sure to trigger the View content event on the product detail page and send the required data with the trigger. To add the products to the catalog using pixel you must send data of the product to Facebook by using any of the provided mechanism such as OpenGraph

```
<meta name="og:title" content="Proname" />
<meta name="og:description" content="Product Description" />
<meta name="og:url" content="https://myexample.com/procat/productname" />
<meta name="og:image" content="https://myexample.com/images/virtuemart/product/hat2.png" />
```

Comment: @aleksdj I undeleted the post as it could be of help to someone else.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Resulted in a long discussion with the Facebook support, but in the end they got it fixed (they, because my pixel started working without me changing anything more, but their tech department took care of it). However, I am not sure, if they changed something system wide or just for my case.

So try to connect it once again, maybe it just starts working. Otherwise get in touch with the support.

Comment: How can I get in touch with the support team? I tried with many channels (forums, developer group, etc.) but no one was a successful one....  could you post a link to that discussion you had it?

Comment: Use the Facebook chat support and escalate your issue to email support. This is what I did. Just message their page via messenger here: https://www.facebook.com/facebookadsupport/